# Adding lua source to project giving linker error

Tags: c++, lua, lua-api

I've added the lua source to my DLL project (removed lua.c and luac.c). I have the below code as a DLL project in VS and I'm getting a lua_createtable() linker error (lua_newtable() is a macro that calls lua_createtable()). What's odd is lua_createtabel() is defined in lapi.c which an .obj is getting generated so not really sure why I get the linker error.

```
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include "lualib.h"

#define PI (3.14159265358979323846)

static int miles_to_km(lua_State *L)
{
    double miles = luaL_checknumber(L, 1);
    double km = miles * 1.609;
    lua_pushnumber(L, km);
    return 1;   /* one result */
} /* end of miles_to_km */

static int circle_calcs(lua_State *L)
{
    double radius = luaL_checknumber(L, 1);
    double circumference = radius * 2 * PI;
    double area = PI * radius * radius;
    lua_pushnumber(L, circumference);
    lua_pushnumber(L, area);
    return 2;   /* one result */
} /* end of miles_to_km */

static const luaL_Reg testlib[] =
{
    { "miles_to_km", miles_to_km },
    { "circle_calcs", circle_calcs },
    { NULL, NULL }
};


/*
** Open msg library
*/
DLL_EXPORT int luaopen_msglib(lua_State *L)
{
    //luaL_openlib(L, "msg", msglib, 0);

    lua_newtable(L);
    //luaL_setfuncs(L, testlib, 0);
    //lua_setglobal(L, "Test");

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: extern "C" { your  luaincludes } why remove lua.c?

Comment: ty so much! lua.c seems to just be for creating the lua executable, which I don't need since I'm just adding the source to my DLL project.

Comment: Any ideas why calling package.loadlib("LuaDLLTest.dll", "luaopen_msglib")() gives 'attempt to call a nil value'. Something messed up with my function exposed in the DLL I suppose.

Comment: @user441521: Try `assert(package.loadlib("LuaDLLTest.dll", "luaopen_msglib"))()` to get an error message in case `package.loadlib` fails.

Comment: Better edit linit.c and add your library.

Comment: You should find in the lua source `lua.hpp` as one of the include files. You can just include that instead of the three headers separately and it correctly decorates the functions under C++.